# PIL install with jpeg

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I install  PIL1.2 with python2.7 on linux mint 64.
I have run `python setup.py build_ext -i`. And I got following infomations.

```
running build_ext
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.2a0 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.2a0
platform      Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 05:13:16)
              [GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** TKINTER support not available (Tcl/Tk 8.5 libraries needed) 
--- JPEG support available
*** WEBP support not available 
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
--- LITTLECMS support available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
To add a missing option, make sure you have the required
library, and set the corresponding ROOT variable in the
setup.py script.

To check the build, run the selftest.py script.
```

**But when i ran `python selftest.py`. I got `jpg` error **

```
'--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.2a0 TEST SUMMARY 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Python modules loaded from ./PIL
Binary modules loaded from ./PIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- PIL CORE support ok
*** TKINTER support not installed
*** JPEG support not installed
*** WEBP support not installed
*** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not installed
--- FREETYPE2 support ok
--- LITTLECMS support ok
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Running selftest:
**********************************************************************
File "./selftest.py", line 50, in selftest.testimage
Failed example:
    try:
     _info(Image.open(os.path.join(ROOT, "Images/lena.jpg")))
    except IOError:
     pass
Expected:
    ('JPEG', 'RGB', (128, 128))
Got nothing
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of  58 in selftest.testimage
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
*** 1 tests of 58 failed.
```

**Why can't it pass the test**
By the way PIL1.7.1 can work on my computer. But I I can't convert `YcbCr` to `numpy.array`. And They said version1.2 had fixed this bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by

```
aptitude search  python_pip
pip uninstall PIL
pip install pillow
```