# How to install packages in Python 3? - PIL on eclipse python33 beginner

Tags: python, eclipse, python-imaging-library, pydev

I am very new in using python 
how to install PIL on eclipse am using python 33
in my code I see this error

> from PIL include Image

```
Error : no module named PIL
```

I have tried

> import Image

no errors at the import part on eclipse but there is an error on

> Image.*open*(image_stream)

Error: Undefined variable from import: open PyDev breakpoint

when I run from command window 
no module named Image

The file site-packages is empty I don't know how to include packages

Comment: possible duplicate of [PIL install with jpeg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604416/pil-install-with-jpeg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question should be

> How to install packages in Python 3?

1. go to https://www.python.org/downloads/ and download Python 3.4 or newer. (This has the pip command to install packages)
2. install it.
3. [open a console](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Open-a-Command-Prompt-window)
4. type

   ```
   pip3.4 install pillow
   ```

   if this does not work then use the full path (example for windows):

   ```
   C:\Python34\Scripts\pip3.4 install pillow
   ```
5. the import statement should work now

   ```
   import PIL
   ```

If you search for this you can find many answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+install+PIL